# Post Via Email - How to send Attachments with it (e.g. PDF File or JPEG Image)?

Tags: attachments, email

In regards to the 'Post via Email' feature, does anyone know of a way to send an attachment with it?  In this case it would be a PDF document.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few plugins that offer that capability. Look at [Postie](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/postie/) for example.

Austin Passy did presentations at a couple WordCamps last year demonstrating how to set up the plugin. There's a video on wordpress.tv of [his presentation at WordCamp PDX](http://wordpress.tv/2010/09/18/austin-passy-photos-via-email/).

Answer (score 0):

According the the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_to_your_blog_using_email#Extensions_and_Add-ons)

> Posting by email does not support attachments and any attachments sent with the email will appear in their raw form in the blog post.

Comment: I think the question is how to add support for attachments, not whether or not the posting by email feature currently does support attachments.